# Related product does not show when selecting product from configurable product

Tags: configurable-product, related-products

I have created a configurable product with subproducts (simple products)- so far so good - I select and price and picture change and I can place the correct product in the basket - but I would like the text, SKU and my related products to change as well.

NB. The related product is assigned to the children (simple products) - I would like to show related depending on selection.

I hope someone can help with this - thanks

Christian

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, when choosing options, the *images* and the *price* will change, but **not the SKU, the description und related products.**

In order to display this elements of the selected product, you can create a [Plugin (Interceptor)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html%5D) for `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable::getJsonConfig()` where you need to add missing elements for each simple product.

Switching elements when selecting an option can be implemented in `vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/base/web/js/swatch-renderer.js` and `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js` depending on the [type of attribute](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-create-configurable.html#product-variation-attribute-requirements) (`Visual Swatch`, `Text Swatch`, `Dropdown`).

---

I made `VCT Product Info Switcher` module on Magento Marketplace that solves this problem (including SKU, description and related products switching).